# My @Published variable isn't being updated in a function in my swift ui app

Tags: swift, firebase

so in my app a function by the name of `fetchName()` is fetching the first name from firestore. I later see that it retrieved the data successfully however it has not written the data to the variable. When I read the variable it turns out to be empty. Help would be appreciated.

Pull from firestore class:

```
    class UsersManagerModel: ObservableObject {
    
    // variable used for user info
    @Published var firstName = ""
    @Published var lastName = ""
    
    func fetchName(email: String) {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()

        let docRef = db.collection("Users").document("\(email)")

        ... more firestore code...

            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let data = document.data()
                if let data = data {
                    print("data", data)
                    self.firstName = data["FirstName"] as? String ?? ""
                    print(self.firstName)
                }
            }

        }
    }    
}
```

The print statement is the variable that is not returning me the data although I know it has successfully been pulled since the print statement before it successfully displayed all the data. I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Did you use as `@ObservedObject var model = UsersManagerModel()`? or try to update self.firstName in main thread?

Comment: @Won - do you mean Dispatchque.main.async() ?

Comment: @Won - I did you use the observable object.

Comment: Force a 'potential' crash by using `!` instead of `?` this will help you see if there is an error at that line of code: `self.firstName = data["FirstName"] as! String`

Comment: I recommend (1) using Codable to map data from Firestore documents to Swift and (2) implementing error handling so you can see what might be the issue. Check out my blog post https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/ for a comprehensive guide to both.